# Magento 2.1 Change URL's like customer/account/login/ for instance -- Translating URL's in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How can you translate URL's like domain.com/customer/account/login/ and other account URL's?

In vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/frontend there is a file with frontName="customer" but is this the file to edit savely?